# Find opened / closed parenthesis of nested fractions

Tags: php, regex, fractions

For a non-commercial math site I would need a function with which I can detect nested fractions from a string and then apply the following method to the numerator / the denominator

```
var a = nerdamer('divide((numerator),(denominator))');
```

So if the user enters an input such as

```
( a^2-b^2 ) / (a-b)
```

the result should be a+b. However this should also work with nested fractions.

I have tried to accomplish this with Regex but I failed. So therefore I ask here for help.

With best greetings, Leon

Comment: I want to help, but your question is Unclear.  Can you explain the logic? The exact expected output? Some addition sample inputs and your expected outputs for them? I'm not sure regex is the right tool for this task... but I am not sure what I would recommend.

Comment: I don't think regex is right tool for such kind of operations.

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you for your help!

Comment: I will post some more example for the output:

Input user: ((a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3)/(a+b))/(a+b), input output: a+b; note that the function divide from Nerdamer does the whole factorization to (a+b)^3 and then the division

Input user: (4x^2-9y^2 )/(2x+3y)+(4a^2-b^2)/(2a-b); Input output: 2x-3y+2a+b

Comment: I am also not sure if this can be achieved with Regex, but I don't have any other idea how to do it...

Comment: I think the best that you can hope for is a succession of `preg_replace()` calls which would _attempt_ to perform the refactoring, but this is not likely to be a trivial process to code-up.  If you make some progress, edit your question to show us.

Comment: Ok thanks but I doubt that I will be able to do this...